# Issues updating a UIView's frame

Tags: ios, swift

When `viewDidLoad`, I call setup

```
if (searchBarView == nil) {
   searchBarView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: line.frame.origin.y + line.frame.height + 20, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat(44)))
}
searchBarView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: line.frame.origin.y + line.frame.height + 25, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat(44))
```

Later I call this code in `func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {`

```
searchBarView.removeFromSuperview()
scrollView.removeFromSuperview()
scrollView = nil
let newFrame = CGRect(x:0, y:30, width: searchBarView.frame.width, height: searchBarView.frame.height)
searchBarView.frame = newFrame
        
view.addSubview(searchBarView)
view.addSubview(tableViewBooks)
view.bringSubviewToFront(tableViewBooks)
inSearchMode = true
```

Unfortunately, `searchBarView` does not update its frame. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new frame and set to the view

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRect(x:0, y:30, width: searchBarView.frame.width, height: searchBarView.frame.height)
searchBarView.frame = newFrame
```

Instead of this

```
searchBarView.frame.origin.x = 0
searchBarView.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(30)
```

Comment: I did that. Sometimes it works. Sometimes it doesn't

Comment: When it's not working? In which position you tried this code to execute?

Comment: Are you use this on ViewDidLoad method?

Comment: I'm changing the frame in the func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") { function. here's what I'm doing. The search bar shows in position 1. When people click on it, you see the search results and it moves to position 2.

Comment: Would you please put some delay to update the frame?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    // Put your code which should be executed with a delay here
}